# Chance of dying within a year by age, gender, and country?

Tags: data-request

I want to get the dataset that shows a chance of dying within a year (or succeeding survival rate) by age, gender, and country?

For example, I want to know how likely the age 20-24, male is alive next year depending on each country.

Is there any dataset that shows it?

Answer (score 6):

See the national life tables, e.g.

- [UK, Government Web Archive](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20160105160709/http://ons.gov.uk/ons/publications/re-reference-tables.html?edition=tcm%3A77-365199)
- [United States, Social Security](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html)
- [Germany, Statistisches Bundesamt](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Gesellschaft-Umwelt/Bevoelkerung/Sterbefaelle-Lebenserwartung/_inhalt.html)

Or [The Human Mortality Database](http://www.mortality.org/) that collects data from various countries.

Answer (score 3):

Quandl has several databases showing data for mortality. The databases come from sources like the World Health Organization, Centre for Disease Control, the World Bank and the UN. See https://www.quandl.com/search?query=mortality&type=all. Hope this helps...

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]